# The constructor VideoCapture(long) is not visible

Tags: java, opencv

I could not able create the VideoCapture(0) constructor.

```java
public WritableImage capureFrame() {
  WritableImage writableImage = null;

  // Loading the OpenCV core library
  System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );

  // Instantiating the VideoCapture class (camera:: 0)
  VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);

  // Reading the next video frame from the camera
  Mat matrix = new Mat();
  capture.read(matrix);

  // If camera is opened
  if(!capture.isOpened()) {
     System.out.println("camera not detected");
  } else     {

     System.out.println("Camera detected ");
```

[image]

I am new to this openCV please help me to capture the video using webcam.
I have using the openCV-4.3.0 version and its jars and x64 dll files.

Comment: can you show videocapture class??

Comment: its not my class its a opencv class.
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

Actually I have used this code only
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_face_detection_using_camera.htm